Nuxt project not running inside iframe but running good normally
I tried many options like even creating a fresh a fresh Nuxt project, still I could not make it work under an iframe. I am receiving the below error,
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
Basically, it points out to the function below inside one of the nuxt files,
function Ae(W) { return globalThis.a.send(W, l.b.POST_MESSAGE_NAMES.HELLO, {}, { domain: l.b.WILDCARD, timeout: -1 }).then(function(A) { return { origin: A.origin } }) }
I have no idea what this function is, but looking at the top, probably vite function.

All I am seeing is Nuxt template loader and not proceeding further. I tried updating nuxt and vite, node modules cleanup, Cloudflare proxy off, x-frame options set to any but still not working.
Its working good with our old Nuxt 2/vue 2 project.
My dependencies:
 "dependencies": {
    "@formkit/auto-animate": "^0.8.2",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.15",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.15",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.15",
    "@fullcalendar/vue3": "^6.1.15",
    "@nuxt/image": "^1.7.0",
    "@paypal/paypal-js": "^8.1.0",
    "@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt": "^1.2.0",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.1.0",
    "@vueuse/nuxt": "^10.9.0",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^1.7.0",
    "countup.js": "^2.8.0",
    "debounce": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.45",
    "nuxt": "^3.12.4",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "v-calendar": "^3.1.2",
    "vee-validate": "^4.12.8",
    "video.js": "^8.16.1",
    "videojs-panorama": "^0.1.7",
    "videojs-vr": "^2.0.0",
    "vite": "^5.3.5",
    "vue": "^3.4.27",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "^11.0.5",
    "vue-multiselect": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "vue-paypal-checkout": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.3",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.10",
    "vue-toastification": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt-primevue": "^0.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.77.2"

}
here is the nuxt config details:
(Omitted App meta and Primevue config for readability)
devtools: { enabled: true },
  spaLoadingTemplate: "./spa-loading.html",
  ssr: false,

  nitro: {
    serveStatic: true,
  },

  router: {
    options: {
      hashMode: false,
      scrollBehaviorType: "smooth",
    },
  },

  routeRules: {
    "/": { prerender: false },
  },
alias: {
    quill: process.dev ? "quill/dist/quill.js" : "quill",
  },

  imports: {
    dirs: ["stores", "stores/*/", "composables", "composables/*/"],
  },

  plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/axios.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/autoAnimate.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/veeValidate.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/flatPickr.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/sweetAlert.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/vueToast.js", mode: "client" },



  { src: "~/plugins/vueMultiselect.js", mode: "client" },
  ],

  modules: [
    [
      "@pinia/nuxt",
      {
        autoImports: ["defineStore", "storeToRefs"],
        storesDirs: ["./stores/**", "./custom-folder/stores/**"],
      },
    ],
    [
      "@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt",
      {
        storage: "localStorage",
      },
    ],
    "nuxt-primevue",
    "@nuxt/image",
  ],

